# How to detect webshell

Tags: siem

I implemented an SIEM and right now looking for solutions to detect webshell upload to IIS and Apache web servers.
What are the requirement for detecting webshell upload?

Comment: You are looking for the "indicators of compromise" for a webshell.

Comment: any upload of a php file?

Comment: I am looking for solutions for detecting any webshell. for example web servers logs, WAF logs, monitoring uploaded file content via anti-virus, etc. am I correct? is there any more?

Comment: That's a LOT of different things to check. Each one will perceive of and detect a "webshell" differently. I think you need to narrow down your question.

Comment: As for what will detect it, that's *entirely* up to the technology you use in your environment.

Comment: I am more looking for detecting webshell upload via web server log. is it possible? or what is the simplest way?

Comment: @alitavakoli that's really still too broad. Even *if* the file to be executed on your server is somehow uploaded via a HTTP Post or something that ends up in your log files, why are you assuming you can detect the content of something being pushed to your server via the logs? No webserver these days supports "uploading" of files to be executed – that's always some server-side software running behind your webserver. So, I really have my doubts you getting anywhere here.

Comment: Your question makes it sound like "uploading code by a third party to be executed on the server" would be a normal function of your server. It's not. It's an exploitation of a vulnerable part of your system, and thus, and since webshells don't have any fixed form (but being something that your webserver executes which shouldn't be there or shouldn't be executed), this question has no single answer.

Comment: @Marcus you are right I cannot read content of the file uploaded in logs but what if I check the extentions of file names that are loged or can I install an anti-virus on web server for checking file content?

Comment: @alitavakoli You really don't have an overall picture of all the different shapes in which webshells come. It's very rare that some software let's you upload let's say a .php file and put it somewhere you can call it... that's really not how any of this works.

Comment: @Marcus when attacker use vulnerabilities like sql injection, XSS and RFI for uploading malicious scripts, this is not detectable via web server logs?

Comment: XSS is a client-side vulnerability, usually, so no, not at all. SQL injection happens... with the SQL server, and the webserver doesn't log that, so no.

Comment: web server can not log uploading malicious script (uploader) via sql injection that executed in URL?

Comment: @alitavakoli that's one of a million shapes SQL injection can take place. I've personally not seen any web application that takes things it sends to an SQL server in URLs in *years*; this is, luckily, not the 1990s, and if your web application uses user-supplied strings from URLs in database queries, its developer should probably read about prepared statements (seriously, in 2018, this is basic stuff that's been standard for a decade). URL modification is by far not the only way to interact with a server...

Answer (score 1):

You might need other solutions to integrate on your SIEM.

- Anti-Malware / EDR - For detection on your endpoint.
- IPS / Advanced Threat - For detection on any outbound connection to any C2 or correlated signature from your IPS.
- Integrity Checker on your servers (i.e. Tripwire)
- Server hardening / patches

Comment: I am agree with all of your solutions and are correct but  in the case of integrity check, which path I have to check?

Comment: integrity checks don't check single paths. They check for whole systems to be unmodified. So, check *all* the paths?

Comment: @Marcus as far as I know, it is possible for checking integrity of special path via AIDE, OSSEC and Tripwire. my question is which path? there are lots of paths in web server that are changing and I do not know in which path my webshell will be located.

Comment: read my comment. *All* the paths. No-One but the attacker who knows which vulnerability they will exploit knows the path. Obviously. Because, otherwise, people would simply disallow writing to that path? I mean, that's the main usage of SELinux, for example.

Comment: It's a case to case basis on which path you will monitor.
In a production server perspective, their should be a few modifications on the server. Basically all of the path should be monitored for modifications.